# How to get test result in fixture

Tags: typescript, playwright

is it possible to get test result in Playwright fixture? See the sample code below, how to access test result(passed/failed/skipped) after `await use(todoPage);` in `testFixture`? It would help me decide whether it need to do some afterEach job in the fixture.

Or shall I add a `testFixture.afterEach()` in the `myTest.spec.ts`? Is it a best practise?

```
const testFixture = base.extend<{ todoPage: TodoPage }>({
  todoPage: async ({ page }, use) => {
    const todoPage = new TodoPage(page);
    await todoPage.goto();
    await todoPage.addToDo('item1');
    await todoPage.addToDo('item2');
    await use(todoPage);
    await todoPage.removeAll();
  },
});

testFixture ('should add an item', async ({ todoPage }) => {
  await todoPage.addToDo('my item');
  // ...
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just figured out it myself..

```
const testFixture = base.extend<{ todoPage: TodoPage }>({
  todoPage: async ({ page }, use, testInfo) => {
    const todoPage = new TodoPage(page);
    await todoPage.goto();
    await todoPage.addToDo('item1');
    await todoPage.addToDo('item2');
    await use(todoPage);
    await todoPage.removeAll();

    if (testInfo.status === testInfo.expectedStatus) {
      console.log('so I can do something here only when it is expected result');
      console.log('it also could be === passed');
    }
  },
});

testFixture ('should add an item', async ({ todoPage }) => {
  await todoPage.addToDo('my item');
  // ...
});
```

see https://playwright.dev/docs/api/class-testinfo#test-info-expected-status for more information